# Execute shell command xdotool in C++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, exec, xdotool

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

//  Trying to execute:
//      xdotool mousemove 1500 1500

//    char command[] = "/usr/bin/xdotool\0";
    char command[] = "xdotool\0";
    char argument[] = "mousemove\0";
    int src_x = 1500;
    int src_y = 1500;

    char x[5];
    memset(x, 0x00, 5);
    sprintf(x, "%d", src_x);
    char y[5];
    memset(y, 0x00, 5);
    sprintf(y, "%d", src_y);

    cout << "command is " << command << "\n";
    cout << "argument is " << argument << "\n";
    cout << "x is " << x << "\n";
    cout << "y is " << y << "\n\n";

    char *args[] = {argument, x, y, nullptr};
    return execvp(command, args);
/*    char *args[] = {x, y, nullptr};
    char *com[] = {argument, nullptr};
    return execvpe(command, com, args);
    */
}
```

What is wrong with this code?
The command runs, but seems to interpret every argument as another execution.
Not sure, but I believe it is running:

> xdotool mousemove
>   xdotool 1500
>   xdotool 1500

*This is the output:*

> command is xdotool
>   argument is mousemove
>   x is 1500
>   y is 1500
>
> mousemove: Unknown command: 1500
>   Run 'mousemove help' if you want a command list

Answer (score 0):

When assembling `args`, you need to add "xdotool" as the first argument.

From [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) for `execvp`:

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename
>   associated with the file being executed.

So it should be `char *args[] = {"xdotool", argument, x, y, nullptr};`.